# Redirect in php throws 520 error CloudFlare

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare with codeigniter framework and I am facing strange problem while trying to redirect the script to another page when the action is completed, server use to throw error 520(cloudflare server)

```
$input = $this->input->post();

if(!empty($input)){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $r = $this->userModel->login($input["email"], $input["password"]);
            if($r["success"] == "t"){

                $this->userModel->setSession($r["_user_id"], $r["token"]);

                //Both redirect methods does not works
                //echo '<html><head><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$this->glob->exec_redirect().'"></head><body></body></html>';
                redirect($this->glob->exec_redirect());
                die();
            }else{
                $data["errors"] = $r["message"];
            }
        }else
            $data["errors"] = validation_errors();
    }
    $this->load->view("user/login", $data);
```

This script work fine without cloudflare, also the script work fine with cloudflare without redirect functions.
Demos:

[Sample which throws error](https://www.plac24.com/user/login)

**user**: test

**pass**: test12

Sometimes you should try more then once to crash

[Sample without redirect](https://www.plac24.com/user/testlogin)

Works fine, user is logged in just have to redirect Manuel.

Regards.

Comment: Try to remove the `die()`?

Comment: I did it and it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged in, and it worked. Then, I logged out and tried to login again and I saw the 520 error you're talking about.

I think it has something to do with your redirect URL.

```
https://www.plac24.com/user/login?rdr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plac24.com%2F
```

As you're redirecting them to your website, do you need the http://?

Comment: There are couple of page which are using https such login, register ... and they are forced on https beside others are force http!!!

Comment: the problem seems to be the form action it was only # which means the same url: `https://www.plac24.com/user/login?rdr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plac24.com%2F`I replace it to `https://www.plac24.com/user/login` and now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything that sends large cookies or headers? That's a possible cause & support can help troubleshoot.

Comment: The $this->userModel->setSession() method saves all the necessary sessions thats all!